# How to add height to existing height?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

For example I want to add `20px` to `<div id='example'></div>`, which is currently `20px`.

I could get the existing height and add `20px` and input it as the new height, but I wish to learn if there is a better way that might work like a `+=` operator.

Comment: Why not just use the `+=` operator?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can pass a function into `height()` that has the element's current height as an argument and the `return` of the function will be the new height:

```
$('#example').height(function (index, height) {
    return (height + 20);
});
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/grajh/

Docs: http://api.jquery.com/height/

Answer (score 24):

There are many ways to do it: http://jsperf.com/jquery-height-vs-css-height

[jsbin.com/utaduy](http://jsbin.com/utaduy)

```
$('#example').css( "height", "+=20px" );
```

---

```
$('#example').height( $("#example").height() + 20 );
```

Comment: Still not working for some reason. I though it was because my element didn't have a height property set to begin with. However, when I set one and tried it again, it still didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

That way:

```
$('#example').height( $('#example').height() + 20 );
```